# How to inspect web flutter elements

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I am looking for a way to inspect flutter web elements. I saw there is a question but no proper answer. That is why I am asking the same question again. Is there any tool or add-on that I can use to capture the specific element's attributes like class name , label etc? Thanks.

Comment: Do you a Javascript code for "capture the specific elements"? If so, you can execute Javascript codes using `evaluateJavascript(...)` (refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65473988/9455325).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to automate the flutter web app using selenium. So, for that, I need to capture the specific element's attributes like class name ,  label name etc.. Is there way to get these attributes, please ?

Comment: Yes you can do that one. Code it in Javascript first, then add it into the `evaluateJavascript(...)`. Sample: `final String className = await webViewController.evaluateJavascript('document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].className');`